# AJAX $_POST multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

Ok so I want to pass jQuery multidimensional array through AJAX to a php which will do some stuff.

The array can vary in size but for some help here is a basic example of what the array looks like before going through ajax when i see it in the console.log:

[image: Console Log]

My Ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'proccess-results.php',
    data: testData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() { // do stuff }
});
```

I can get things like the child and the email with:

```
$child = $_POST['child'];
$email = $_POST['email];
```

But the sections array I cant figure out how to get. I've tried:

```
$sections = $_POST['sections'];

foreach ($sections as $section) {
    echo $section['section-name'];
    echo $section['section-score'];
    // etc...
 }
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

EDIT-->

Network response:

```
Mikearray(2) {
  ["child"]=>
  string(4) "Mike"
  ["email"]=>
  string(18) "test@example.co.uk"
}
Array
(
    [child] => Mike
    [email] => test@example.co.uk
)
```

So I guess my nested arrays aint even coming through. :(

Comment: have you tried just var_dump($_POST) to see what you are actually getting?

Comment: do a print_r on your server side to see the structure you receive and post it to help us know what the server really receives..

Comment: the php file is just processing the data sent by ajax. I cant see the data from the php file

Comment: @Mikode Go into the browser's console, go to the Network tab, and then the Response section of the AJAX call. It will show the raw response, including anything you print with `var_dump`

Comment: Javascript doesn't support associative arrays. The element in the array sections are probably coming through as objects instead of an array.

Comment: `Mikearray(2) {
  ["child"]=>
  string(4) "Mike"
  ["email"]=>
  string(18) "test@example.co.uk"
}
Array
(
    [child] => Mike
    [email] => test@example.co.uk
)
`

Comment: Sorry that looks terrible, will update the initial post

Comment: Looks like the section array didn't make it to the server side.

Comment: JSON.stringify your payload before you post it, decode it on the PHP side, and your arrays'll be there.